# Use Redux as an initial component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm using Redux as an initial state in a component used to edit the name of a current selected item (containing these properties : "name", and "selected"). It's used as a local *initial* state, because I want to update the Redux global state only when I click on a save button (that I didn't implemented yet).

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        item: this.props.item
    }
}
```

My render function contains an editing name input :

```
<TextField
    id={"name"}
    value={this.state.item.name}
    onChange={e => this.updateName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

The updateName() function is :

```
updateName = (value) => {
    var newItem = this.state.item
    newItem.name = value
    this.setState({item: newItem})
}
```

Here, I can selected an item, the default's value of the input changes following the name of the item I selected (when I select an item, the state of Redux is updated, so is the state of the component and the text in the input). Everything is working as intented.

When I write into the input, the written text changes, but the action of selecting an item do not update the text of the input anymore (it should follow the name of the selected item from Redux, like before I entered text).

Is it because the reference to the this.props.item (and afterward the updates of Redux) is lost as soon as I update the component state with this.setState() ? But how can I correct this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `constructor` is called only once, while your input is a controlled component, commanded by your state.

What you need to do is to update your component state based on redux state so, to this in the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

**Please note**: updating the state using a prop is considered an anti-pattern.